# How do I make the FlowDocument's pagewidth bigger than the limit (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I increase the PageWidth  of the FlowDocument?
The maximum PageWidth of a FlowDocument is only 1000000 which is 9600 characters. I am using the FlowDocument inside a RichTextBox.

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). Can you explain X?

Comment: I've eddited the question. I am trying to get over the limit of the PageWidth of a FlowDocument because a RichTextBox has text wrapping build in. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#remarks) : 

Text always wraps in a RichTextBox. If you do not want text to wrap then set the PageWidth on the FlowDocument to be larger than the width of the RichTextBox. However, once the page width is reached the text still wraps.